# Sublime Text 2 folding tags

Tags: sublimetext2, folding

Is there functionality to fold only specified html tags in Sublime Text 2/3?  For example:
`<span>`lot of text`</span>`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You just have to find the required starting tag using <kbd>ctrl+F</kbd>, then select them all using <kbd>ctrl+D</kbd>. After that to fold them just press <kbd>ctrl+shift+[</kbd>.

Comment: Will not ctrl+ combination increase size of text?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older post, but as I was looking for the same thing I thought I'd post the solution I found.

If you hover your mouse in the gutter, arrows will show up for folding/unfolding blocks of code.

Comment: the question is about a specified tag, for example to show only all <p>-html tags closed..

Answer (score 1):

Ensure Package Control is installed. Instructions are found here.

In Sublime Text, press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>＋<kbd>Shift</kbd>＋<kbd>P</kbd> (Win, Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>＋<kbd>Shift</kbd>＋<kbd>P</kbd> (OSX)

To bring up the quick panel and start typing `Package Control: Install Package`

Select the command and it will show a list of installable plugins.

Start typing `BracketHighlighter`, when you see it, select it.

> preferences > package setting > BracketHighlighter > key bindings - user

```json
[{
  "keys": ["ctrl+alt+]"],
  "command": "bh_key",
  "args": {
    "plugin": {
      "type": ["__all__"],
      "command": "bh_modules.foldbracket"
    }
  }
}]
```

Restart to be sure everything is loaded properly.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> -shortcut key
Enjoy!